# Offline Installation of python & pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, offline, setuptools

I need to install python on a sever to run scripts but the server has no access to the internet.

The server has access to a local network that has access to the internet*. I would like to use pip to manage the packages through a local network directory as specified [here](http://www.nyayapati.com/srao/2014/06/how-to-pip-install-python-packages-offline/).

How can I install pip, python and their dependancies on a windows machine, offline so that I can use pip, as specified in the link above to manage the packages I require?

*For Clarity: I have no ability to mirror, hack or otherwise to get information to pass through the local network directly from the internet.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem you are facing? You have identified what you want to do - but failed to ask a question.

Comment: "I want to be able to install pip, python and their dependancies on a windows machine, offline" - edited the prefix to make it strictly a question. More of a grammatical issue rather than an unclear statement

Comment: Well, you download the Python installer from https://www.python.org/. Then you put that file in some place your server can access, and run the installer on the server. pip is already included starting with Python 3.4 (and starting with 2.7.9, if you need Python 2 for some reason).

Comment: It's unfortunate, but the link provided above, despite being exactly what I wanted, `pip` no longer supports the flag `--download` anymore, so I couldn't follow those directions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official Python installer for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) has no other dependencies. It runs completely offline.

For other packages that may have dependencies (that are difficult to install on Windows); Christopher Gholke maintains a [list of Windows installers for common Python packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). These are msi installers (or whl files) that are self-contained.

They are designed to work with the official Python installer for Windows - as they use its registry entries to identify the install location.

You can download these and move them to your Windows machine.

Beyond those two - if you have further requirements you can use tools like [`basket`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Basket/1.0) to download packages and then provide the location as a source for offline pip installs; or create your own pip repository.

If you do decide to create a local pip repository, it is better to create a pip *proxy* ([see `pypicache` for example](https://pypicache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) this way you are only requesting those packages that are required, rather than trying to mirror the entire cheeseshop.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2023 - Python 3.x

The Python 3 `.exe` installers **may** require internet access to download a number of dependencies, *depending on the options selected*. There is a mechanism to download these to a local directory given [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=installing#installing-without-downloading).

1. Download the appropriate installer to a new directory on your Windows machine that does have internet connectivity. e.g. `python-3.11.4-amd64.exe` from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).
2. Open a command prompt and navigate to that directory
3. Run the installer with the `/layout` option e.g. `.\python-3.11.4-amd64.exe /layout`
4. This will download the installer and optional components *(including debug databases)* to the local *or specified* directory.
5. At this stage it is probably a really good idea to run your virus scan on the downloaded files.
6. If you have dependent packages, e.g. `pandas` & `Django` that you also need to install you will need to install that specific python onto your online machine, including `pip`.
7. You can then use that python installation in the form *(example for downloading pandas and & Django plus dependencies to `package_dir`)*:
   `\Path\To\That\Python\python.exe -m pip download --dest package_dir pandas[all] Django` *If you want to be able to run the pandas test suite you will also need pytest and Hypothesis on the download line.*
8. Copy both the download directory and the package directory to your offline machine.
9. On that machine run the installer `.exe` - in the directory containing the optional components. You can add command line parameters or use an `unattend.xml` file as detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3.12/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui).
10. In a fresh command prompt `cd` to where you put the packages and run something like: `python -mpip install --find-links=. pandas[all] Django` *you may need to give the exact filename of the top level packages.*
11. Test your installation!