# How to install python at a pc without internet access

Tags: python-3.x

I have full python 3.6.3 in my pc(WINDOWS 2010).I need somehow to take python and install it to a  pc(WINDOWS XP HOME) that has not internet access at all.Also i need to incule some libraries at the offline internet pc.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible it is a binary file that you need to execute after all. You need the executable file that is appropriate for the operating system you have.

For Python 3.6.3 refer [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/), at the end of the page there is a "Files" section. If your operating system is Windows download Windows executable installer (if you know it is 64-bit system download "Windows x86-64 executable installer". If it is not or you are not sure, download "Windows x86 executable installer").

Download the necessary executable file from a computer having access to internet, move the file to the other machine e.g. via USB drive. Then run the executable file.

If not Windows, I suggest reading the release page above a bit more.

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος exactly! I made additions to my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. What about some libraries?

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος if not lots of files, you can download and carry tar.gz files from the library that you need Refer here for [how to install from archieve](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/). BTW I realized there is a comprehensive answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181678/offline-installation-of-python-pip Best!

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect... The Python 3.6 installer attempts to make an outbound internet connection and will fail with an error message (`0x80072efd - Unspecified error`) if it can't.